# Iterate and Update same Collection in VBA

Tags: vba

My requirement is to iterate through a VBA collection , and based on certain
condition update the subsequent records in the same collection.

For example lets say "TMasterList" is a collection which has total of 4 records , 
while 2nd record gets processed in the below loop,
I need to update 3rd and 4th record and then continue with the loop(ie process 3 and 4th).

```
For Each objEachTmapping In TMasterList


Next
```

Any suggestions on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the index, checking the bounds if needed:

```
Dim i As Long, max As Long
max = TMasterList.Count

For i = 1 To max

    TMasterList.Item(i).value = Foo

    If i + 1 < max Then TMasterList.Item(i + 1).value = Bar
    If i + 2 < max Then TMasterList.Item(i + 2).value = Qux

Next
```

This assumes that there is a reference in the collection, if its a type it cannot be modified in situ.

Comment: should performance be an issue I'd limit the loop to `max - 2`, removing `if` statements from it and placing them just after it